# How do I add existing remote branch to my locally cloned repository?

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch, git-remote

I would like to add this branch to my local clone:
https://github.com/dmitriz/mithril.js/tree/rewrite

For some unclear reason, it did not get cloned.

So I ended up with local directory without that branch. Is there any easy way to clone this branch too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is checking out to this branch.

```
$ git checkout rewrite
```

Git will switch to a new branch, tracking the remote one. Here is the message you should get

```
Branch rewrite set up to track remote branch rewrite from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'rewrite'
```

Comment: Doesn't work:
`$ git checkout rewrite` ---

`error: pathspec 'rewrite' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Comment: Well it should, it works for me: https://gist.github.com/Richard-Degenne/76498f52de45f3a926f119a3c0c0ae7f

Comment: I suspect that you're having a problem with you Git configuration, even though I don't know what it is.

Comment: You are right, I used the Github client to clone, which is apparently unreliable. Once cloned from CL, it worked as you describe.

Comment: I'm interested in seeing what's causing this behavior though. Happy my answer helped.

Comment: I can guess my clone process was not properly completed with my Github client for Mac, the CLI is more reliable it seems.

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev: I wonder if perhaps the GitHub client defaults to a `--single-branch` clone. If so, that would be Wrong. :-) But it would explain the problem.

Comment: @torek It did clone multiple branches in the past. But with large repos (like that one), it did get "lazy" and give up in the past, though this was the first time that happened without any notification.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the repository you initially cloned is your `origin`.

So just do `git fetch origin` and it should pop up on `git branch -a` - after that you can easily check it out using `git checkout -b rewrite origin/rewrite`.

A possibe explanation is that this branch was simply not there when you initially cloned it and you never fetched all (new) branches.

Comment: It didn't show up, and the last command got the error: `fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'rewrite' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/rewrite' which can not be resolved as commit?`

Answer (score 0):

If you clone a repository you already have all branches. All you need to do is to create a local branch from it since it is a distributed scm.

```
git checkout -b rewrite origin/rewrite
```

You can also have other name for your local branch or have several copies of it.

Comment: Doesn't work:

`$ git checkout -b rewrite origin/rewrite`

`fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'rewrite' at the same time.`

`Did you intend to checkout 'origin/rewrite' which can not be resolved as commit?`